# Kotlin android Smart cast to 'BottomSheetBehavior app is crash

Tags: android, kotlin

I do this :

```
private fun initComponent() {
        // get the bottom sheet view
        val llBottomSheet = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_sheet) as LinearLayout

        // init the bottom sheet behavior
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(llBottomSheet)

        // change the state of the bottom sheet
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)

        // set callback for changes
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {}
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
        })

}
```

And when I start my app is crash at line :

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
```

and this is a log :

```
Smart cast to 'BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout!>!' is impossible, because 'bottomSheetBehavior' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time
```

And i do not have any idea what I should to repair this...

and this is xml file which I get in my project :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="250dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Dandelion Chocolate"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I try change a ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout but it do not help . Still my application is crash when I open it

Comment: Add also you `xml` layout part (with this view)

Comment: @Boken I put xml file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first step, you have to change root view (in your layout) from:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

to:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

because `BottomSheet` needs `CoordinatorLayout` for it's behavior.

---

In the next step, you have to modify your layout:

- move `app:layout_behavior` from root in to `CardView`
- move `app:id` from root in to `CardView`

---

In the last step, modify casting of the layout from:

```
val llBottomSheet = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_sheet) as LinearLayout
```

to

```
val llBottomSheet = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.bottom_sheet)
```

In layout you have `CardView`, so casting `as LinearLayout` is not correct.

---

## Full working example:

Code:

```
private fun initComponent() {
    // get the bottom sheet view
    val llBottomSheet = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.bottom_sheet)

    // init the bottom sheet behavior
    val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(llBottomSheet)

    // change the state of the bottom sheet
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED

    // set callback for changes
    bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {}
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
    })
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="250dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Dandelion Chocolate"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hi I have one more issue , maybe you can help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093880/android-nestedscrollview-inside-in-bottomsheetbehavior

Answer (score 1):

You can use `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior` only in a child of `CoordinatorLayout`.