# Android NestedScrollView inside in BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android

This is part of my xml code. I have on partent CoordinatorLayout and this is a BottomSheetBehavior, next I have a big view and I put this view inside in NestedScrollView  , because I have to scroll this. Now I have a issue, When I scroll up BottomSheetBehavior i have a BottomSheetBehavior on full screen but I can not scroll my view up, I do not see what I have. I try change a NestedScrollView   to ScrollView but it does not help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="85dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    >  
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/temp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10sp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt_find_connection"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="aaa"
                        />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/bt_find_connection">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/user_info_panel"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
                                android:layout_width="50sp"
                                android:layout_height="50sp"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="0sp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                                android:layout_weight="3.5">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_user_mail"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_name"
                                 />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
                                android:layout_width="50sp"
                                android:layout_height="50sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_active_tickets"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/user_info_panel"
                         />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/list_tickets"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_active_tickets" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_tickets"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/list_tickets"
                            android:layout_marginTop="25sp"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/buy_ticket_panel"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="130dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tickets"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
                          >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/tv_purchase_of_tickets"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"

                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_purchase_of_tickets"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                                  />

                                </RelativeLayout>

                                <RelativeLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/iv_ticket"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                                 />

                                </RelativeLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/middle_control"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="170sp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/buy_ticket_panel"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="0sp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/parking_panel_top_control"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"

                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.35"
                                      />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_actual_city"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_above="@+id/parking_zone_frame"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                                 />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/parking_zone_frame"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="60sp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                                 />

                                    <RelativeLayout
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_city_parking"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Kraków"

                                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_parking_zone"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_city_parking"
                                            android:text="Strefa A"
                                  />

                                    </RelativeLayout>

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="10sp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                             />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="0sp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/park_and_drive_panel_top_control"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"

                                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.35"
                            />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_nearest_parking"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_above="@+id/frame_park_and_drive"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                               />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/frame_park_and_drive"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="60sp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                                      />

                                    <RelativeLayout
                                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                                        android:layout_weight="1">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_parking_name"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Mały Płaszów"

                                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_free_places"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_parking_name"
                                            android:text="150 wolnych miejsc"
                                        />

                                    </RelativeLayout>

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_purses"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/middle_control"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                          />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/list_wallets"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_purses" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_event"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/list_wallets"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="180sp"
                            android:layout_height="120sp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_event"
                   >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/control_frame"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="10sp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_events"
                                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"

                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                                    android:layout_weight="0.35"
                                 />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/events_display"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
                    />

                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my main_activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <include layout="@layout/sheet_map" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: where in a main layout your are defining this file?edit with that file

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri I edit my post

Comment: you dont need to use coordinate layout for bottomsheet ,you can use their linear,relative or constraint layout and then you can include that file in your activity_main.xml

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri ok but a layout which is NestedScrollView is not scrolled , an application whant scroll app a bottomsheet

Comment: did you to data in scrollview

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri yes and I have a lot of textVIew in NestedScrollView

Comment: what you want to achieve can you put screenshot?

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri At the beginning I want to slide BottomSheetBehavior from the bottom of the screen. View and later scroll the view that does not change on the screen and is in my NestedScrollView

Comment: it seems your scroll view is working fine. it is already scrolled to last Relative Layout above your control_frame.

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri a view which is in NestedScrollView does not fit on the screen

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri a scroll VIew is not working fine I do not see what is on the bottom

Comment: @KikiKala2 a screenshot would be great so we could understand better. and help you out asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it add line `android:fillViewport="true"` inside NestedScrollView
and setHeight NestedScrollView = match_parent

Comment: set height to "match_parent" was helpful